# Is declaring a variable as a class-level constant better for performance than a local variable?

Tags: java, scala

I have a method which is expected to be invoked very frequently:

```
private def escapeSpecialCharacters(term: String): String = {
  val specialCharacters = Pattern.quote("""\/+-&|!(){}[]^~*?:""")
  val specialCharsClassGroup = s"([$specialCharacters])"
  val escapedFirstMatch = "\\\\$1"
  term.replaceAll(specialCharsClassGroup, escapedFirstMatch)
}
```

would it help the performance if the three `val`s were declared as class-level constants (because this way they are potentially recomputed on each invocation), or is the compiler smart enough to realize that the final product (`specialCharsClassGroup` and `escapedFirstMatch`) is constant and then just keep it stored as a constant?

This code is in Scala, but I guess it applies just as well to Java.

Comment: If there is any difference it will be so minute that it is negligible...

Comment: I would probably define these in a companion object _not_ for the sake of performance, but just because it makes the code easier to read. If I see these definitions in a method I have to scan them to see whether they depend on the method parameters or call other instance methods—if they were on a static object their (lack of) dependencies would be clear.

Answer (score 2):

A few observations:

While it's true that premature optimization has its limitations, as TravisBrown says, you really want to minimize the cognitive load of what you're expressing.

Regexes, in particular, make everyone ask where is it compiled? b/c pls don't make me compile a regex on every invocation.

Seek clarity both for dependencies and for a basic granular sense of where the costs are contained.

So clearly you want to define compiled regexes in a companion and not use `String#replaceAll` if you are reusing the regex, as you are here. Use `Regex#replaceAllIn` instead.

It's not obvious that you'd want to escape every escapable character. That's what `Regex.quote` is for, to escape the string tout court. And BTW, use `Regex.quote` instead of `Pattern.quote` just because.

Also, it's not clear why you don't use triple-quotes for `escapedFirstMatch`.

You're really asking the reader to switch between three different contexts: triple quotes, string interpolator and single quoted literal, which are currently different enough with respect to escapes that it's confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler won't do that for you. How does it know that the method `Pattern.quote()` will return the same value each time? You should make that a field or constant for increased performance.

That said, the performance gain from moving it might not be all that important. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: Thanks. I guess my case is a bit too specific. I was wondering about the general case. E.g. if all the constituent `val`s were only literals. Could you comment on that please?

Comment: @Zoltán I'm not really sure, sorry.

Comment: I'd argue that situations like this is what constants (`static val` / `static final`) are made for.

Comment: @Clashsoft is totally right, these should be class constants. Even if they're used only in the scope of a single method. Java doesn't have static local variables like C does.